# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str' when using newly created list

Tags: python, excel, list

I am using an external Excel spreadsheet to get a list of values. Currently, the script works perfectly for what I want it to, taking the list and doing with it what I need. I can also change the list to other sheets and columns that already exist. However, when I create a new column (on both an existing and new sheet) and try to use this list, I get this message:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Desktop/List.xlsx', sheet_name='Country Codes')
Countrylist = df['Country'].tolist()

extension = '.xlsx'
Clist = [x + extension for x in Countrylist]
Countries = Clist
```

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Desktop/List.xlsx', sheet_name='Country Codes')
Countrylist = df['CountryA'].tolist()

extension = '.xlsx'
Clist = [x + extension for x in Countrylist]
Countries = Clist
```

In the first example, I am using the already created **Country** column. In the second example, I am using the newly created **CountryA** column. The first example will run perfectly, the second example will fail at `Clist = [x + extension for x in Countrylist]`, giving the error message above. The below shows an example of the two data sets that I am using. It is the same data, copied over. I tried the same script for the Country Codes in column B too (which were previously created) and it worked, so I believe it is something to do with the new columns.

[image]

Does anyone know why I cannot use the script for newly created column (CountryA)?

Comment: How did you create CountryA column and do you expect it to be same as Country column?

Comment: @Dewansh Chhatri - I created it manually, and the column values would change. Another user has said that I need to convert the whole thing to a string and this has worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number or `NaN` value in the `CountryA` column; probably from Excel autoformatting an empty cell.  You can convert the entire column to a string before using it via:

```py
Countrylist = df['CountryA'].astype(str).tolist()
```

and then run the rest of your script.

Comment: Brilliant, It appears that there was a NaN value in there. When I converted it, it worked. Thank you